# Weird error "No plugins loaded for this entry: xarray_image" when using hvplot

Tags: python, hvplot, holoviz

Here's the code how I use hvplot

```
from hvplot.sample_data import us_crime

columns = ['Burglary rate', 'Larceny-theft rate', 'Robbery rate', 'Violent Crime rate']


us_crime.plot.violin(y=columns, group_label='Type of crime', value_label='Rate per 100k', invert=True)
```

But get the following error, does anyone know what might be wrong ?

```
ValueError: No plugins loaded for this entry: xarray_image
A listing of installable plugins can be found at https://intake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugin-directory.html .
```

Answer (score 1):

`pip3 install intake-xarray` (followed by a restart of Jupyter) solved this problem for me. No additional imports were required.

Answer (score -1):

Works fine for me as long as I `import hvplot.xarray` first to install hvplot xarray support:

[image: sample output]